# Within a multi select, I need to be able to get the value of the currently selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

Edit:I think I have confused you guys with what I need. If I select val1 I need the function to return val1. If I then select val2, with val1 still selected as part of the multi select, I need to return val2. Then I can use the values to set the id and name of rewly created inputs.

I have a select list that has multiple="multiple"

I want to create a text input associated with each selected option and set the id and name of the new input based on the value of each newly selected option, but I always get the value of the first item from the onchange event. Not the first value, but the first selected value. So if I choose val2 first, that is returned, but if I choose val1 first then val2 the id and name will be the same as when val1 is selected.

```
 <select id="multiSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>      
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
 </select>
```

I have used the following function and it returns the first value.

```
 $("#multiSelect").on('change', function(evt, params) {
   alert($("option:selected", this).val());

 });
```

This will return the first selected option. If I then choose the second option, I still get the first value.  I need to get the value of whichever option has been selected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to save previously selected elements and compare them with newly selected ones:

```js
let selectedOptions = [];

$("#multiSelect").on("change", function() {
  const newSelectedOptions = $(this).val() || [];
  const addedOptions = newSelectedOptions.filter(option => !selectedOptions.includes(option));
  const removedOptions = selectedOptions.filter(option => !newSelectedOptions.includes(option));
  selectedOptions = newSelectedOptions;
  console.log("addedOptions", addedOptions);
  console.log("removedOptions", removedOptions);
});
```

```html
<select id="multiSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="value_1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value_2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value_3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice one @Regent but if you deselect an option the value is "" and if you deselect all the value is null.

Comment: I know how old this post is, but you have no idea how long I've been trying to get this to work. Your answer is EXACTLY what I've been looking for. Thank you!!! I did wrap most of it in an if statement to make sure it doesn't fire if it's deselected ( `if(!direction)...` ). Thank you again!!

Comment: @Anna I rewrite code in more modern way and with separation of added and removed options. You can now simply use part with `addedOptions`

Answer (score 0):

You get the selected values on change:

```js
 $("#multiSelect").on('change', function () {
     var selected = $.map($('option:selected', this),

     function (e) {
         return $(e).val();
     });
     alert(selected);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It shows all selected elements, not new (clicked) one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/jb7ckarp/

```js
$("#multiSelect").on('change', function(evt, params) {
  $("#myDiv").append("<span id='mySpan'><input type='text' name='" + $(this).val() + "' value='My name is: " + $(this).val() + "'/>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want, or not :D http://jsfiddle.net/mnm2oaeo/

```
<select id="multiSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

var items = [];

$("#multiSelect").on('change', function(evt, params) {

  var selected = $(this).val() || [];

  if (selected.length == 0)
    items.length = 0;
  else {
    $.each(selected, function(i) {
      if (items.indexOf(selected[i]) == -1) {
        items.push(selected[i]);
        alert(selected[i]);
      }
    });
  }

});

</script>
```