# highlight div depending on select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

i have here a select option and a div that has the same content of select option value

```
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div id="textvalue">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
</div>
```

what i want to do is whenever i click the select option 1, the div below that has the same text will be highlighted,

Can someone help me how to code it on jquery? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS class to apply 'highlight' styles to your elements. Remove the class from all elements within `#textvalue` and then filter out the `<div>` that contains the value selected. You can the add the class back.

Put all of this inside a `change` event handler to have the functionality invoked when your change your `<select>`.

Optionally trigger the `change` event for your `<select>` on page load, to invoke the function:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('#textvalue div').removeClass('highlight').filter(':contains('+this.value+')').addClass('highlight'); 
}).change();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugpfqg5x/2/)

---

If the `<div>` values aren't distinct, you will have to go about using `.filter()` a different way:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var value = this.value;
    $('#textvalue div').removeClass('highlight').filter(function(){
        return this.innerHTML == value;
    }).addClass('highlight'); 
}).change();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugpfqg5x/4/)

Comment: Using `:contains` could become problematic if the values aren't distinct. Choose 4 in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ugpfqg5x/3/

Comment: thanks for answering, yes,  i think that would cause a problem if i have a value like 31-39

Comment: Glad to have helped, did you see my updated solution? Thanks to @j08691 for the pointer.

Comment: @labli No worries at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery: ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/aLsqn58f/))

```
$('#textvalue > div').each(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
$(this).attr('data-tx', text);
});

$('select').on('change', function() {
var selected = $(this).find(':selected').html();
$('#textvalue').find('div[data-tx=' + selected + ']').css({'background-color':'red'});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need in 4 step:

1. Get value from the selected option

   [Within a multi select, I need to be able to get the value of the currently selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240887/within-a-multi-select-i-need-to-be-able-to-get-the-value-of-the-currently-selec)
2. Select the n-length div using JQuery `eq` method

   [Define jQuery "eq"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428438/define-jquery-eq)
3. Add a class in the div

   [jquery add remove class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245934/jquery-add-remove-class)
4. Add css code to style your class like following:

   .highlighted{
     background-color: yellow;
   }

Hope this helps!